# Wordpress Custom Post Type Search by title

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I created a Custom Post Type for my Wordpress Site, `"public"` and `"publicly_queryable"` args are true, `"exclude_from_search"` is false. The type supports the title and I want to find my the entries by the standard wordpress title with the wordpress search.

I don't know why, but the custom post type entries are not listed when I search for the title of the entries. Does anyone know why or do you need further information?

Comment: share your post type args and query search args

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question should include a clear outline of your *specific* coding-related issue, a summary of what you have already tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we have enough information to be able to help!

Comment: 'labels' => $labels,
        'description'=> 'xxx',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'supports'  => array( 'title'),
        'taxonomies' => array(),
        'has_archive' => true,
        'can_export' => false,
        'menu_position'  => 5,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'rewrite'  => array('slug' => 'xxxx' )

Comment: Search args are default.

To create post type entries I use advanced custom fields, except the title which I put in through the standard title field.

Comment: Hope it will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27833926/search-query-for-post-title

Answer (score 1):

just do below instead of false put true

```
'exclude_from_search' => true
```

**'true' - site/?s=search-term will not include posts of this post type.

‘false' - site/?s=search-term will include posts of this post type.**